# Read DOCX files using javascript in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, client-object-model, rest

Can we fetch contents of DOCX files uploaded in a doc library from javascript code ?  I could easily read a TXT file ref : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx) .

Any pointers on how to read contents of a DOCX through javascript object model/REST API

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB tool/service available to read word files in Sharepoint online.

For workaround you must have download the file using client object model and then read the content of the files using INTEROP or .NET object model.